# What happens at the compiler level when casting one Objective C object to another

Tags: objective-c, casting

I know that in C casting one variable to another type tells the compiler to act as if that variable is of that type and size in memory.

Example:

```
int* a = (char*)b;
```

Take the value of b (which is a 1 byte memory address) and store that in the 4 byte variable a. (Correct me if i'm wrong)

How does this work which casting an Objective-C object? 
I also understand that each object is just a C struct holding a pointer to its class, instance variable list, etc.

If I have a class which is a subclass of UIView called MyView and I am passed a pointer to a UIView, maybe a method argument, and I do this:

```
-(id)setupThisViewForMe:(UIView*)aView {
    MyView* newView = (MyView*)aView;
    newView = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,100.0f,100.0f)];
    [newView takeOverTheWorldWithMyMethodInSubclass];
    return newView;
}
```

What exactly is the compiler doing at compile time?

Answer (score 4):

> What exactly is the compiler doing at compile time [when you cast Objective C objects]?

Almost nothing: the compiler performs checks related to ARC, making sure that you are not coercing a weak pointer into a strong variable or vice versa, but other than that, the compiler trusts you to do the right thing. Of course if you "lie" to your compiler, it will "pay back" with unsupported message exceptions at runtime.

Comment: +1 Figured as much, this actually leads to more questions, which I'll ask later :)